# Why Do we need CDN? Can we replace it with different servers at different geographical Location?

Tags: server, cdn

A CDN is essentially a network of geographically dispersed servers. Each CDN node (also called Edge Server) caches the static content of a site like the images, CSS/JS files and other structural components.

As per my understanding CDN caches the static content of site, but instead of using CDN if we directly put different server at different geographical location and based on the location user can hit those servers and get the data faster, What is the issue with this approach? Why do we need CDN in that case. Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

> ... if we directly put different server at different geographical location

That's what CDNs do. They replicate your static site to content to various data centers across the globe.

> What is the issue with this approach?

Nothing wrong, we already use the "separate-servers" in CDNs.

---

Turns out that you are re-defining CDNs in your second paragraph unknown to you.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network):

> A content delivery network, or content distribution network (CDN), is a geographically distributed network of proxy servers and their data centers.